# ValueError: Cannot assign "5687": "Table2.kid" must be a "Table1" instance

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

`Table1`  where i get the data from a management script that calls a certain API.
`Table2` also gets data from an Api. The scenario is `xid` & `kid` are same, so i have implemented a `OneToOne` relationship so that i can easily get the related item from `table1` in context of `table2`. `Table1` has to be populated in order to populate `table1`, as only then assignment of `table2` instance can be done. `5687` Already exists in table1 but still i get the error:

> `ValueError: Cannot assign "5687": "Table2.kid" must be a "Table1" instance.`

**`Models.py`**

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    xid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField()

class Table2(models.Model):
    kid = models.OneToOneField(Table1,primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vid = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    g_amount = models.IntegerField()
```

This is my script code that is same for both management commands that get me data.

`Management/commands/script.py`

```
    """ API CODE """

    data = {
        'kid': kid,
        'vid': vid,
        'g_amount': g_amount

    }
    if Table2.objects.filter(vid=xid).exists() or Table1.objects.filter(xid=kid).exists() is False:
        continue
    else:
        # print(data)
        instance = Table2(**dataff) 
        instance.save()
```

Or should is there a way i don't need to have `OneToOne` relationship. Using Django's ORM a query can be constructed that will get combine the instance from these two table in one and place it in a Virtual Table so that i don't loose ORM capabilities.

Comment: 5687 is one of the `kid`

Comment: try this `data = {
    'kid': Table1.objects.get(xid=kid),
    'vid': vid,
    'g_amount': g_amount

}`

Comment: @JPG tried your context and this error - `dashboard.models.DoesNotExist: Table1 matching query does not exist.`

Even though instance with 5687 already exists in table 1

Answer (score 0):

The conditional check on models field is applied after declaring the data dict. It will be declared after the if condition so that the dict can be saved with condition.